# Que ou où dans Tu tomberas en maladie la journée que/où tu seras chargée de ce dossier

Tags: choix-de-mot

Tu tomberas en maladie le jour que/où tu seras chargée de ce dossier difficile.

Tu tomberas en maladie dès le jour que/où tu auras la responsabilité de cet usager difficile.

Comment: En France au moins, **tomber en maladie** est extrêmement rare par rapport à **tomber malade**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si on doit l'utiliser, « que » doit avoir dans ce contexte syntaxique la nature de conjonction; c'est ainsi parce que si on conçoit « que » en tant que pronom relatif, donc le pronom relatif object, il doit être l'objet du verbe « être », ce qui est du non-sens, et donc ce n'est pas le pronom relatif. Mais il n'existe pas de construction de la conjonction  avec le mot jour; il en existe avec certains autres mots, comme « fait » (**Le (seul) fait que** + ind. (pour insister sur la réalité du fait) ou + subj.). Il en existe une qui contient « jour », mais elle ne convient pas.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jour))  **Du jour que** (littér.). À partir du jour où.
> ♦ Or ces parias étaient souvent des gens qui tiennent ce qu'on appelle le haut du pavé, mais qui pour M. de Charlus avaient cessé de le tenir du jour qu'il avait été brouillé avec eux

Il n'y a donc qu'une possibilité, l'utilisation du pronom « où ».